# Route53 DNS issue with Django Elastic Beanstalk app

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. My zone is public and I have simple routing for the A records pointing to the EB alias. I even tried a CNAME to no avail.

Browser error in Chrome -- The site can't be reached. DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem. DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE

I even did a test response within the console. Everything checks out but there is something funny happening between the Route53 -> EB handshake. The EB alias works just fine by itself.

I would love some pointers. Perhaps I need to configure something within Django settings?

[image: Current Config]

Comment: Accessing EB directly, using its default URL, works? So the only issue is with R53?

Comment: Also do you actual own realtime**.com domain? You bought it and registered using R53 as well or used some other registrar, such as namecheap?

Comment: Correct. The default URL works fine in EB. Yes, I purchased the domain through AWS prior to setting up Route53. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I that case, I don't see why it wouldn't work. Did you try to use your domain with something else just to see that it works in general, and the issue is only with EB?

Comment: I am having the same issue here: the EB domain URL works perfectly, but the domain alias for that doesn't. It's a Django app, the domain is also listed in the ALLOWED_HOSTS, but I  can't figure out what can be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the resolvers on the AWS side even though I didn't transfer the domain. They provisioned the wrong resolvers and I had to manually change them out to a different set. I only discovered this fact after creating a support case.